# setText to a saved preference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, textview

I have saved a highscore to shared preferences, i would like to display the high score on the main menu and have it stay there even if you close the app and reopen it.

i have got it to work so that it changes the textview to the highscore when you click load highscore but i want it to do it automatically.

```
//saving the highscore
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    static SharedPreferences settings;
    static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

// When 'back' button is pressed save the highscore to settings

            editor = settings.edit();// Create a new editor
            editor.putInt("highscore", HighScore); // Storing integer       
            editor.commit();

// When 'Show' button is pressed
    public void showPreferences(View v) {
        int highscore = GameActivity.settings.getInt("highscore", 0);
        Toast.makeText( MainMenu.this,
                    "Your Highscore is: " + highscore,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tvScore.setText(Integer.toString(highscore));

    }


//current on create

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_start);
        tvScore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGuessGame);


    }
```

Comment: Just load it in `onCreate()`.  Where do you initialize `settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreate()`, after you define the `TextView`, set the text with the value you got from `SharedPreferences`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_start);
    tvScore= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGuessGame);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(....); //
    int highscore = settings.getInt("highscore", 0);
    tvScore.setText(""+highscore);
}
```

Comment: when i run the application with that code i get Unfortunately Game Start has  Stopped.

Comment: You have to initialize settings first. I edited the code

Comment: Initialize `settings` the same way you do in `GameActivity`.

Comment: SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: What is the traceback? (what does logcat says?)

Comment: what specific error should i be looking for? just so i can narrow the redness down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77131/discussion-between-rafael-cardoso-and-carlle-robinson).